# How did armor differ from place to place?

Tags: armors

I don't have much knowledge about history so I was wondering how much armor/weaponry changed in different regions. What factors would influence it? I imagine a lack of natural resources would have an impact on military, but wouldn't trade fix that problem?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Unfortunately, while it's interesting, this question isn't really suited for Worldbuilding.SE for two reasons. One is that historical questions, without a fictional basis, are off-topic here (but are likely to be accepted on [History.SE](https://history.stackexchange.com/). Second, your question is really broad! You may have better luck getting good answers by focusing on a more specific topic such as a region, time period, or type of armor or weapon.

Comment: VTC as too broad. Fashion. Tradition. Specific conditions, such terrain, or who are the likely enemies. Doctrine, e.g. Roman emphasis on infantry vs. Persian emphasis on heavy cavalry. For a great example of how much equipment can differ, look up the [Battle of Nicopolis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Nicopolis) between the best of the best western crusader army and the Ottoman Turks (1396). (Spoiler: the westerners lost badly.) As for trade fixing the problem, how do you do that when you are busy isolating yourself from the world, such as for example Japan did for 300 years?

Comment: Thanks for the info. Im aiming for historical info so I have something to base myself on for a fictional world, so while I do understand japan's situation, it isn't quite the same on my world (the isolation problem just isn't there)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Many Factors

Which include and are not limited to:

- resource availability (what is available?)
- weapon technology (what does armor need to defend against?)
- Metallurgy/Woodworking/Other skills (can these resources be used?)
- Preferred Tactics (How do people like to fight?)
- Terrain (What limitations does the environment impose? Teutoburg Forest comes to mind as a good example.)

## Welcome to a World of Study

People literally become professors and dedicate their lives to this. As an armchair historian, some examples come to mind...

For instance, Europe, with its relatively plentiful iron ore, could armor their knights in full metal suits. Japan, on the other hand, had less plentiful (and less quality) ore, so they had to figure out how to make wood armor.

The advent of fast-firing guns also shows how technology changes armor. Plates began being tested with guns to prove themselves as useful (making them 'bullet-proof'). Guns got a little more powerful, so people decided to wear less armor because it just was not effective against the guns.

Rome (end-of-republic era) had success with heavy infantry w/ sword, shield, and javelins because their shield/armor protected them from 'most' threats so they could easily close. Other people at the time were more into spear and shield tactics. (With some notable exceptions, like the Nubian kings and the Britons...)

## No Desire for a Military History Degree?

Find a good military history podcast or something like Historia Civilis on youtube. (It is a gem!) These can be good entry points to this fascinating subject.

Comment: About lack of mineral resources, couldn't they buy what they lack from other nations? And how does terrain affect it all exactly?

Comment: @AlcinoAlbino: Western European knights-in-armor were the response to a severe demographic crash (throughout the Middle Ages, western Europe had fewer people than it had in the 2nd century!) and an extremely bleak economy. These two conditions conspired to make having standing armies impossible. As a consequence, war was something of an elite occupation, in which few people engaged, and many of those people were wealthy and individually important; medieval western European armies would have been laughed at by any self-respecting empire which existed at the same time.

Comment: @AlcinoAlbino: ... The point being that right at the same time as the western European age of knights-in-armor, the Turks, for example, living right next door, and possessing just as much iron ore, but having an actual functional state and a real functional economy, did have the capacity to maintain a standing army and did not seek to cover their soldiers in full armor. And they beat any western so-called army whenever they were given the opportunity.

Comment: @AlexP like at the Siege of Vienna... Wait, this is a great example as to why this is a *COMPLICATED* subject! There are generalizations and exceptions (include multiple possible reasons for those exceptions). Enough to publish papers!

Comment: @PipperChip: What siege of Vienna? The Ottomans did not besiege Vienna during the Middle Ages. (The Hungarians did it, just at end or just a little after the end of the Middle Ages; but the Ottomans didn't get to try to take Vienna until later, once towards the end of the Renaissance and then again in the Early Modern period.) (Both Ottoman sieges of Vienna happened well past the age of knights-in-armor.)

Comment: @AlexP I was thinking of the 1529 Siege of Vienna, which most people consider Renaissance (my bad), but still had people wearing plate. Suleiman has so much going for him but things didn't pan out. The point here is that military history is complicated and no WB or history post will do justice to the field.